# How does the rejection sampling lemma work in the proof of HVZK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, lattice-crypto, commitments, ring-lwe

[image]

In this protocol,

Q1: how does the commitment work? What if the prover sends $\textbf{t}$ directly, and then sends $s_m,s_r,s_{\textbf{e}}$?

Q2: How does the rejection sampling lemma work?

refer to this paper [Reference](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/889.pdf)

Comment: For Q1, look at the last sentence of the proof of Theorem 4.1. The hiding property is needed to deal with aborts. Sending t in plain is obviously not hiding.

Comment: t is already a commitment, does it have the hiding property? I mean if abort, then the simulator outputs (t,d, ...)，t = a*\mu  + b*\rho + e (generated by the protocol)